# Meteor Call - Exception in template helper

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a method call in client, but I get

```
Exception in template helper: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: https://www.example.com
```

I'm using a Meteor method to parse a URL in XML to get some data, so my variable is a string URL

Method

```
 rank: function(postAttributes) {
    check(postAttributes, {
      url: String
    });
    var alexa = require('alexarank');
    var alexaSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(alexa);
    var result = alexaSync({url: postAttributes.url});
    return result.rank;
  }
```

Client Call

```
function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = this.url;
     var post = {
      url: $(a.href)
    };
    Meteor.call('rank', post, function(error, result) {
      // display the error to the user and abort
      if (error)
        return throwError(error.reason);
      // show this result but route anyway
      return result;
    });
  }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps $(a.href) is not returning a String and the template executes the url as if it was javascript code.

Try using:

```
url: '' + $(a.href)
```

Comment: same result Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Comment: Could you please run this checks and post the results the console gives you? I am not sure but I think there is something odd with how your create the object post.

Try running this before "var post = ..." :

`console.log( typeof($(a.href)) ); console.log($(a.href));`